# Hide Facebook Video via the Graph API

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created an app which allows the user to upload a custom video to their own Facebook profile. But, by a specific client request, I need to hide that video right after posting it. I already looked at the is_hidden property from the API documentation, but it doesn't seem to work.

Has anybody already tried that? Any help is very much appreciated!